# how to change the background of table view , quickdialog box

Tags: iphone

I am following the tutorial about a quick dialog box to create a form as below
[image]

Now, I would like to change the background of this form. Does anybody know how to achieve this, please advice me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if you want to show an image as a background:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPattern:@"your_image_here"];
```

or

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128 green:128 blue:128 alpha:1.0];
```

If this does not work, you can set the `backgroundView` property of the table view:

```
tableView.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_here"]]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `backgroundView` property of the `UITableView`.

If you want to use an image, just create a `UIImageView` and set `backgroundView` to it.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

You may also use the `contentMode` to adjust how the image fits in the view.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try some of the properties that `UITableView` either inherits or declares:

`@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *backgroundView`
`@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor`

The first is probably what you are going to want. It is declared by `UITableView`. The second is inherited from `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the background color of the table view; it may require that you change the table view style from grouped to plain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting a background colour try this...

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //replace with your colour
```

But if you want a pattern image don't use that method... Do this..

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init]; //needs memory Managment (arc example)
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"]];
tableView.backgroundView = v;
```

This is because if the UITableView is group styled the and you have a patterned background image as the tableviews backgroundColor then it's applied to the edges of the cells too but as they're separate views the pattern becomes incorrect.

Hope it helps.